# Why are some notes written in uppercase in MIMIC-III?

Tags: mimic-iii

I see that some notes from the medical personnel entirely written in uppercase in [MIMIC-III](https://mimic.physionet.org/). Why?

Comment: @close voters: questions pertaining to specific open data sets are on topic. See http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Can you precise your question with the type of document you find those notes? Which data set you are referring to?

Comment: @magdmartin Thanks, good point, added in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When they type their progress notes, some nurses use all caps and some don't! Just personal style!